# Equivalence of two optimization problem？

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

problem 1:
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{}{\text{maximize}}
& & -b^T\mu-(1/4)\sum^{n}_{i=1}(c_i+a_i^{T}\mu-v_i)^2/v_i \\
& \text{subject to}
&& v \succeq 0.
\end{aligned}

problem2:

\begin{aligned}
& \underset{}{\text{maximize}}
& & -b^T\mu-1^Tw \\
& \text{subject to}
& & A^T\mu-v+w+c =0 \\
&&& \mu \succeq 0 ,v\succeq0, w\succeq 0
\end{aligned}
where  $A =(a_1,a_2,\dots a_n)$

how to these two problems are equvlanent  ?

Comment: Why do you believe them to be equivalent? They _are_, I just want to know what the context is, and what you have done to figure this out for yourself. Let me give you a hint: for an individual term within the summation, what value of $v_i$ is optimal?

Comment: @MichaelGrant got it , thx .